# PHP push to message queue; process with multithreaded python client?

Tags: php, python, message-queue

Here's what I'm trying to do: use PHP to push a message into a queue (either `Beanstalkd`, `IronMQ`, `Amazon SQS`).

Then I want a Python script to instantly pick up the message. I guess I'll just have 1 Python script running a `while(true)` loop to keep polling the message server?

Then process it using a new thread for each job. If there's 10 messages in the queue, I want python to run 10 threads, 1 for each job.

My questions are:

1. Is this a solid way of doing things, or is there a better way to set this up?
2. How do I ensure my Python script is up and polling forever?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a solid way of doing things, or is there a better way to set this up?

Sounds reasonable to me, although if you're expecting a large number of simultaneous jobs, you may want to limit the total number of threads by using a [thread pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern).

You won't gain much more CPU performance, for CPU-intensive threads, when the total number of threads exceeds the total number of CPU cores, and if the threads require significant disk I/O, you'll want to limit them to avoid thrashing the disks.

> How do I ensure my Python script is up and polling forever?

It's common for daemon processes to have another process which monitors them, and restarts them if they crash or become unresponsive. A simple cronjob might suffice for this purpose.

Comment: Is [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) what I want to take care of my Python script?

Comment: @StephenSarcsamKamenar I can't really recommend any specific solutions because I've never used anything other than a cronjob. Real daemon processes will typically `fork()` child processes and monitor the children, but this may be more complicated that you need. At the end of the day, as long as your daemon is well tested, you may not need to monitor it at all.

Comment: There's a solution for daemon crashing problem -- [supervisord](http://supervisord.org). This guy will do: 1. monitor your process 2. start your daemon without init.d script 3. respawn process if it died.